# Cisco WLC custom logout page

Tags: java, networking, cisco

I am using Cisco WLC where I need to use custom logout page. Can anyone please help me or guide me that what should be the code for this logout page and how can I configure this page in Cisco WLC ?

And if anywhere we find any Cisco WLC where this custom logout page is used, how can we get that specific file used for this purpose ?

Thanks in advance.